# Always empty aggregations django elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I use django-elasticsearch-dsl and I have the problem that aggregations always return empty value to me.

I need all the different publishers and the different authors of the search results.

Document:

```
@registry.register_document
class BookDocument(Document):
   author = fields.ObjectField(properties={
    'name': fields.TextField(),
    'name_reverse': fields.TextField(),
    'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
    'slug': fields.TextField(),
   })
   editorial = fields.NestedField(properties={
    'name': fields.TextField(),
    'slug': fields.TextField(),
    'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
  }, include_in_root=True)

  class Index:
    name = 'books'
    settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                'number_of_replicas': 0}

  class Django:
    model = Book
    fields = [
        'title',
        'isbn',
    ]
    related_models = [Author, Editorial]  # para asegurarnos que cuando se actualice un author, se reindexa los libros

  def get_queryset(self):
    """Not mandatory but to improve performance we can select related in one sql request"""
    return super(BookDocument, self).get_queryset().select_related(
        'author',
        'editorial'
    )

  def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
    """If related_models is set, define how to retrieve the Book instance(s) from the related model.
    The related_models option should be used with caution because it can lead in the index
    to the updating of a lot of items.
    """
    if isinstance(related_instance, Author):
        return related_instance.book_set.all()
    elif isinstance(related_instance, Editorial):
        return related_instance.book_set.all()
```

Search:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import MultiMatch, Match
from elasticsearch_dsl import A



s = Search(index='books')
s = s.query("match", title="SECRET")
s = s[0:20]
s = s.highlight('title')
s.aggs.bucket('by_editorial', 'nested', path='editorial')\
.metric('max_lines', 'max', field='lines')
response = s.execute()

print(response.aggregations)

for item in response.aggregations.by_editorial.buckets:
    print(item)
```

Or:

```
s = Search(index='books')
a = A('terms', field='author')
s.aggs.bucket('by_author', a)
response = s.execute()

print(response.aggregations)

for item in response.aggregations.by_author.buckets:
    print(item)
```

what am I doing wrong? in elastic the data is correct.

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:

I have found a way to solve the problem to get all the data of an object in an aggregation:

In the model:

```
@property
def agg_data(self):
    return 'id##{}~~name##{}~~slug##{}'.format(self.pk, self.name, self.slug)
```

In the Document:

```
editorial = fields.ObjectField(properties={
    'name': fields.TextField(),
    'slug': fields.TextField(),
    'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
    'agg_data': fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={'raw': fields.KeywordField()}
    ),
})
```

Query:

```
s = Search(index='books')
s = s.query("match", title="SECRET")
s.aggs.bucket('by_editorial', 'terms', field='editorial.agg_data.raw') 
response = s.execute()
```

When I get the results of the aggregation, I parse the field to mount the search filters on the web.

Comment: I dont see the 'lines' field in your model.

Comment: I have found a possible solution. How about?